# Image download from server URL android

Tags: php, android, eclipse, image

For now, i am able to download the image that i uploaded into my server. My upload is using php script to file open a image to store the .jpg file in the server. But i want to know how to retrieve the new image from my server to my android application. What i meant is every time the user upload the image, the image will replaced the old image file (using the same file name) in my server folder.

When i reload the image in my application, it still gives me the old image even though the image not longer exist. Later i found out that i need to go the url and refresh the image then the new image will be loaded in the android application. I want to know how can i refresh the url without using the browser to refresh the image every time the user upload new image. Thanks!

**My question might not be clear/good but i really needed help and im new to android development**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A pragmatic approach: When the user uploads a file, also make a txt/xml-file with the current date in it.

Make you Android application poll the txt/xml-file. Store the date in the txt/xml-file (in a database). When polling verify if the date in the file is newer then the one you stored. If it's newer, download your image.

Comment: hmm. but what should i use to compare which image file is newer?

Comment: i understand what you meant. Im trying your method now. get back to you if i get problem again. thanks!

Comment: Pretty sure it will work. An alternative is sending a message from your upload to the phone .. like push notifications (MQTT or C2DM). However my txt-file approach will be a lot easier (and less intrusive).

Comment: Im still figuring out your idea. I still dont know how to implement. Basically, i create a .jpg file with the user's id and datetime as the name of the file. So Im thinking of file write a txt file whenever the image is uploaded. am i right?

Comment: Yes. Every upload = New content in txt.

Answer (score 0):

After successfully replaced on server,you have to get url of new uploaded image as response & replace old url by new url.

Comment: every time the user upload new image, the file name is not replaced. only the content/image of the file is replaced. so the url of the image file is always the same.

Comment: Im following his tutorial. http://monstercoda.wordpress.com/2012/04/15/android-image-upload-tutorial/

Comment: $suffix = createRandomID();
$image_name = "img_".$suffix."_".date("Y-m-d-H-m-s").".jpg";  these lines indicates  your images store with new name on server.

Comment: above lines indicate each updated image upload with new image on server.so, url of new image file is change.

Comment: yup. i know but im trying to store as less file as possible. if not the space will be huge. thats why user will only have 1 file and if any changes is made, that file will be replace but the name of the file remains.

Comment: for this,delete previous image from server & upload new image .

Comment: how to delete previous file using php script? Im still stuck at there =(

Comment: send image_name as parameter with new image on server.get value of image_name parameter .If image_name  is null these lines execute $suffix = createRandomID();
$image_name = "img_".$suffix."_".date("Y-m-d-H-m-s").".jpg";